# Trouble with arrays and foreach php oop

Tags: php, oop

Basically I'm trying to create a login, the email validation doesn't seem to pass. I've been looking around for an example but I'm genuinely not sure, doing it statically seems easy enough, however I vaguely suspect using static method would be incorrect to use as a login method(perhaps I'm over thinking it)

```
    <?php

    require ("Database.class.php");

    class Login
    {   
        private 
        $email,
        $password,
        $database,
        $db = null;

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = new Database;
        }

        public function validEmail($email)
        {   
            return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE);  
        }   

        public function emptyPassword($password)
        {
            return(empty($password) !== TRUE);
        }
        public function validPassword($password)
        {
            $query = $this->db->prepare("select * from username");
            return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }


<?php 

require "classes/Login.class.php";
require "loadclasses.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    $email = $pass = "";
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);     

    $email = $post['email-login'];
    $pass = $post['password-login'];        
    $errors = array();

    $fields = array(
     'email-login' => array(        
         'validate' => 'validEmail',
         'message'   => 'Enter a valid email address'
        ),
         'password-login' => array(         
         'validate' => 'emptyPassword',
         'message'   => 'Password required'
        )
    );

    $login = new Login();
    foreach($fields as $key => $value) 
    {
        $validation_result = $login->$value['validate']($value);

        if(!$validation_result) 
        {
            $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $value['message']];
        }
    }

    if(empty($errors)) 
    {
         $success = ['response' => 'true']; 
         session_start();
    }   

}


header('Content-Type: application/json');
if (empty($errors))
{
    echo json_encode($success);
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(["errors" => $errors]);
}
```

As mentioned I'm aware I could do something similar to this:

```
$errors = array();

$fields = array( 
  'username' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validateUsername', 
    'message'   => 'Username must be between three and fourteen alphanumeric characters' 
  ), 
  'email' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validateEmail', 
    'message'   => 'Please enter a valid email', 
  ), 
  'password' => array( 
    'validator' => 'validatePassword', 
    'message'   => 'Password must be a minimum of seven characters' 
  )
);

if(!Validation::validateRepeatPassword($password, $repeatPassword)) 
{ 
    $errors[] = ["name" => "repeatPassword", "error" => "Passwords must match"]; 
}
foreach($post as $key => $value) 
{
    if(isset($fields[$key])) 
    {
        if(!Validation::{$fields[$key]['validator']}($value)) 
        {
            $errors[] = ['name' => $key, 'error' => $fields[$key]['message']];
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem as I mentioned is I'm fairly sure that would be the wrong way to approach this problem

Comment: Btw, `return(empty($password) !== TRUE);` why not simply: `return empty($password);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$validation_result = $login->$value['validate']($value);
```

When you do that, you're actually passing `$value` which is an array (according to the `foreach`). You're not actually passing the email

So, according to your code, you should change your validation array to something like:

```
$fields = array(
  'email-login' => array(        
    'validate' => 'validEmail',
    'message' => 'Enter a valid email address',
    'value' => $email,
  ),
  'password-login' => array(         
    'validate' => 'emptyPassword',
    'message' => 'Password required',
    'value' => $pass,
  )
);
```

And then, change your validation line to:

```
$validation_result = $login->$value['validate']($value['value']);
```

Comment: No problem. Also, I suggest you use better variable names. If, for example, the `foreach` variable was called `$setup` instead of `$value` you'd probably catch stuff like that easily

Comment: Makes sense, I always have trouble with variable names, thanks